# No page but index works on Magento installation

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I have Magento CE 2.0.5 installed locally on Ubuntu with apache2. To view a page other than index, instead of localhost/magento/anotherpage, I have to use localhost/magento/index.php/anotherpage. But this doesn't work for the backend administration page, which I have no way of accessing. Also, no images or stylesheets are loaded on pages.
I know I have mode_rewrite enabled (it's shown as loaded by phpinfo();), and .htaccess in the Magento root folder contains the uncommented line:

```
RewriteBase /magento/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes not able to access other pages in both frontend and adminend its because of index.php problem..

To Work other pages also in Magento2, You can add this below line in database.

Step1: Open database,and Go to table core_config_data.

Step2: Insert this data:

path: web/unsecure/base_link_url
value: http://192.168.1.XX/magento_folder/index.php/
scope: default
scope_id:0

Step 3: Save and now able to navigate otherpages in both ends.